# Question about Injector in Lift

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, lift

As I understand from the [documentation](http://stable.simply.liftweb.net/#toc-Section-8.2) `Lift` provides `Injector` trait (and its implementations) to inject dependencies as follows:

```
object MyInjector extends Injector {...}
​
val myThing: Box[Thing] = MyInjector.inject
```

Unfortunately, it looks too intrusive for me. I don't want my business classes to depend on the `Injector` trait (and its implementation). I would like to keep my business classes clean and free of any framework dependencies.

`Spring`, for example, is not intrusive in this sense. That is, I do not have to add `Spring` imports to my business classes in order to implement dependency injection.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Arguably, Spring is even more intrusive. Instead of adding a simple import to your implementation, you have to move some of your implementation out to Spring's XML.  With all the weak typing, poor refactoring and other maintainability issues that such an approach causes.

Comment: @Kevin I agree that I have to write the glue code in XML with Spring, which is awkward. However my business classes are clean and so Spring is not intrusive in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the Injector trait (neither do I), you do not have to use it. http://scala.sygneca.com/patterns/component-mixins. You can just stick to the [cake pattern](http://scala.sygneca.com/patterns/component-mixins). Does Spring offer you anything that you can't implement with the cake pattern?

Comment: I will probably post a question about Spring vs. Cake Pattern and what I can do with Spring that I can't with Cake.